# Непонятный прикол с объектами

Tags: javascript, объекты

```js
var how_many = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
console.log(how_many);
```

При таком коде выводится объект:

HTMLCollection []

0: div.content

1: div.content

2: div.content

3: div.content

length: 4

**proto**: HTMLCollection

Если же мы код меняем на следующий:

```js
var how_many = document.getElementsByClassName("content").length;
console.log(how_many);
```

То в консоли появляется 0.

Даже если подытожим:

```js
var how_many = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
console.log(how_many);
console.log(how_many.length);
```

То выводится как и тот объект, так и ноль.

Почему?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/jL15phn3/2/ ?

Comment: вероятно где-то в коде переопределяете переменную или проблема в областях видимости. Вообщем нужен полный код

Comment: Я не знаю, обновляют ли браузеры `HTMLCollection`, когда на странице появляется новый подходящий элемент, но если обновляют, то все просто: консоль браузера обычно показывает состояние объекта на текущий момент, а не на тот момент, когда вы вызвали `console.log`. И если ваши `div.content` еще не прогрузились к тому моменту, как вы вызвали `console.log`, то при выводе длинны такой коллекции она будет `0`, хотя если вывести саму коллекцию, то в ней будет ненулевая длина.

Comment: Дополнил вопрос, может быть поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вот тут все понятно и правильно:

```html
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>

<script>
var how_many = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
console.log(how_many.length);
console.log(how_many);
</script>
```

А вот то, что у Вас:

```html
<div id="out1"></div>
<div id="out2"></div>

<script>
var how_many = document.getElementsByClassName("content");
document.getElementById("out1").innerText = how_many.length;
setTimeout(function() {
  document.getElementById("out2").innerText = how_many.length;
}, 100);
</script>

<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
<div class="content"></div>
```

Что тоже, в общем-то, понятно и правильно.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection

> An HTMLCollection in the HTML DOM is live; it is automatically updated
>   when the underlying document is changed.
>
> ... коллекция aвтоматически обновляется, отражая изменения в документе.